# Siblings inherit a property

Tags: united-kingdom, jointly-held-property

Two siblings inherit a property that could be joint or tenants in common. Can one of the owners take a mortgage out ( I assume against the property as  has no other income or property)  without the others consent?

Comment: Where do you live? Country and state.

Comment: I live in United Kingdom

Comment: I can't see how a bank could foreclose effectively on partial ownership of property, so I would expect the practical answer to be "no" whether or not it would be legally acceptable.

Answer (score 7):

Joint tenancy versus tenants in common is key here. If they are tenants in common (ie have a specific share each), it is *theoretically* possible but with emphasis on "theoretically":

[HOA Advice](http://hoa.org.uk/advice/guides-for-homeowners/i-am-buying/buying-a-home-with-a-partner-or-friend-what-to-watch-for/):

> Tenants in common don’t have to own equal shares of the property. They can each act individually, which means they can leave it to a beneficiary in their will. While in theory they have the option of mortgaging their share of the property, in reality finding a lender willing to lend in these circumstances would be difficult because the lender wouldn’t be able to enforce a sale if the mortgager defaulted.

(I am assuming that when you say UK you mean England and Wales. Scotland is usually different for property ownership...)